# Localization and nilradical

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

I am trying to answer a question that has already been posted in here ([About Nilradical and Localization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359133/about-nilradical-and-localization/3359138)). I did not have much success with the first two answers, and the other two mention sheafs, which is something I am not acquainted with.

Basically, I want to show that $\mathcal{N}(R_P) = 0$, for all prime ideals $P$ of a ring $R$, then $\mathcal{N}(R) = 0$, where here $\mathcal{N}$ is the nilradical.

I am aware that localization commutes with taking radicals and intersections, but trying to use the fact that $\mathcal{N}(R) = \cap \{ \text{all prime ideals of } R \} $ and $\mathcal{N}(R) = \sqrt{(0)}$ hasn't led me far.

All I've got so far that makes sense is that $0 = \mathcal{N}(R_P) = (\mathcal{N}(R))_P$, for all prime ideals $P$ of $R$.

Any hints would be very much appreciated. Or perhaps hints that could help me understand the hints given in the link above!

Comment: Do you know that an $R$-module $M$ is zero if and only if $M_P$ is zero for all prime ideals $P\subset R$?

Comment: Yes, proposition 3.8 on Atiyah and Macdonald's book.

Comment: Then what you want follows immediately from your second to last line. But if you want a bit more explicit proof hopefully my answer helps

Comment: This was very polished and elegant, I prefer this one better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a\in\mathcal N(R)$ and consider the ideal $\operatorname{ann}(a)=\{r\in R\mid ra=0\}$. Notice that 
$$a=0\iff 1\in\operatorname{ann}(a)\iff\operatorname{ann}(a)=R.$$
If $\operatorname{ann}(a)$ is a proper ideal, then it is contained in some maximal ideal $M$. But notice that in the localization $R_M$ we have $a/1\in\mathcal N(R_M)=0$; use this to conclude there is some $s\notin M$ such that $sa=0$. Now use the fact that $\operatorname{ann}(a)\subseteq M$ to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: $a/1 = 0$ then there exists a $s \in S = R \setminus M$ such that $s \cdot a = 0 \cdot 1 = 0$. Since $s$ is not an element of $M$, $s$ is a unit and $sa = 0$ implies $a = 0$ and from the equivalences above $ann(a) = R$, which contradicts $ann(a)$ being a proper ideal.

Comment: @Linn perfect!!

Comment: Thank you for your response and your time.